# Negation of the Doob-Dynkin Lemma

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, measurable-functions

Doob–Dynkin lemma: let $( X,Y : [0,1] \to [0,1] )$ be two Borel-measurable functions, where $[0,1]$ is equipped with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Then $Y$ is $\sigma(X)$-measurable if and only if $Y=g(X)$ for some Borel-measurable function $( g : [0,1] \to [0,1] )$.

Does anyone have an "example" of a Borel-measurable function $( X : [0,1] \to [0,1] )$ and
of a function $( g : [0,1] \to [0,1] )$ (not Borel-measurable)
such that $Y=g(X)$ , $Y$ is Borel-measurable and $Y$ is not $\sigma(X)$-measurable?

Thank you

Comment: What do we mean by $\sigma \left( X \right)$-meaurbale? Are $X$ and $Y$ functions or measure spaces?